# Delphi Designer, Is component inherited?

Tags: delphi, ide, designer, design-time

I'm writing a custom component editor, essentially similar to `TActionList` editor in that it allows creation of sub components.
Editor has  buttons to add/delete components.

Now, I'd like to find out if selected component is inherited, so that I can disable the delete button.
I haven't found any such member in `IDesigner` or related interfaces.

If I just go ahead and delete by `Designer.DeleteSelection(True);` then I get an exception:

> Selection contains a component, xxx, introduced in an
>   ancestor and cannot be deleted.

Which is not too bad, but I'd prefer to disable the delete button in the first place.

Comment: You can access the list of your items when you're selecting them in your list view (?) and ask for each item if `InheritsFrom` a certain class.

Comment: @TLama No, that's not it. Daniel talking about visual inheritance, as indicated by the inherited keyword in the .dfm files.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this was possible. Try doing what you describe with a stock `TActionList`. The error message is: `Cannot rename component Action1, component was introduced in an ancestor form.
`. But then click on the action and it disappears anyway and there's another error message: *Argument out of range*. So, the IDE can't get it right!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so apparently there is a way, by checking the `TComponent.ComponentState` for `csAncestor`, so:

> csAncestor in ComponentState

And it's [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TComponentState):

> csAncestor - The component was introduced in an ancestor form. Only set if csDesigning is also set.

Comment: Very good. Well done. Perhaps somebody should tell Embarcadero about this so that they can fix their action list editor!!